# Spring Events vs ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

Newbee to Spring world. I have some knowledge on ActiveMQ. Recently used in one of my projects. While reading about Spring Events raised a doubt.

Spring Events: Publisher -> Listener. We do publish events and we would have created some listeners for that.

ActiveMQ: Publisher -> Listener. We do publish events and we would have created some listeners for that.

So anyone helps me to understand the use cases or difference between these two APIs.

Comment: ActiveMQ is JMS, Spring events are a simple event mechanism. Both are quite different beasts with different usecases.

Comment: JMS is designed to support local application events and distributed messaging. A key advantage to coding to JMS is that your application can use an embedded broker for local application eventing, and then scale to multi-server distributed events without any code change! However, if you code to Spring Events, you'll need to re-factor the app if those events need to become distributed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I can tell, **Spring Events** are an ***application* level events** mechanism, so that different parts *inside* our application can communicate/coordinate. The scope and functionality appear to be quite narrow and small respectively. You can publish events and deal with those events either *synchronously* (default behaviour) or *asynchronously* (using `@EnableAsync` and `@Async`). There is no *broker*. This functionality may be a perfect fit for your application if this is all it needs.

On the other hand, **ActiveMQ** is a full-featured **message broker**. Generally speaking, it runs as an *independent server process* (although it can be embedded in your application). It supports *industry-standard protocols* like AMQP, MQTT, & STOMP which have client implementations on numerous platforms and in various languages. For example, you could send STOMP messages via Websockets from a Javascript client and process those messages with an AMQP client written in .NET on Windows. It provides both a JMS & JNDI client implementation. It supports both publish-subscribe and point-to-point semantics. You can use it as an integration platform and scale it up to multi-node clusters with high-availability for the message data and thousands of remote clients using various protocols or you can embed it into your application and just use it for local events.